# Buffer Overflow issue in environment variable replacement scheme

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Whenever the environment variable's value is larger than its key in this method, I get a buffer overflow. Target is part of a dynamically allocated two dimensional array for tokens. Whenever I replace the token that's an environment variable with a value longer than it, it flows into the next token. I've tried adding a realloc to try and fix it, but it doesn't work or leads to a segfault.

If anyone has any suggestions or can point me at something I"m overlooking, I'd greatly appreciate it, because I have a feeling I'll be kicking myself when I find it out anyway.

The method is:

```
void envReplace(ENV *evlist, char *Target)
{

    if (Target[0] == '@')
    {
        memmove(Target, Target+1, strlen(Target));
        for(q = 0; q<16; q++)
        {
            if(evlist[q].envVariable!=NULL)
            {
                if(strcmp(Target, evlist[q].envVariable)==0)
                {
                    //this is where I'd add the realloc as realloc(Target, strlen(evlist[q].Value))
                    strcpy(Target, evlist[q].Value);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
                printf("Variable not found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("A value that didn't start with @ was an argument\n");
        return;
    }
}
```

The data structure ENV is:

```
typedef struct envStorage
{
    char *envVariable;
    char *Value;
}ENV;
```

Comment: The keys in the Environment Variables aren't being stored with the @ symbol in the beginning if that is relevant. The memmove is meant to get rid of them to make it easier to compare to the key variables themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer to a pointer, like this, and then you can call realloc() inside the function, modifying the original pointer.

```
void func (char **to_change) {
    // Changes the char *target in main()
    *to_change = (char *) realloc(*to_change, 20);
    sprintf (*to_change, "Blablablablabla\n");
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char *target = (char *) malloc (10);
    func(&target);
    printf(target);
    free(target);
}
```

In this example, `func()` writes to the original pointer `char *target` in the `main()` function.

What happens in your code, is that you `realloc()` and assign to a copy of the pointer. The pointer is copied when you call `envReplace()`. When this function returns, the original pointer contains the old memory address, which is no longer valid allocated memory (it was freed by `realloc()`).

Comment: He can call realloc() inside the function and modify the original pointer to where the text is stored. Tried to edit the answer a bit to clearify this.

Comment: I see your point now. That might actually help with the "doesn't work" part.